# ZooKeeper K8s Helm chart from Bitnami

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, bitnami

I am looking for a helm chart that contains the default (most commonly used) configuration for ZooKeeper (config for statefulset, netpol, service, etc.), v3.5.0+.  A chart that I can then use to deploy a ZK cluster in a  k8s cluster.
I was hoping to obtain such a Helm chart (the `values.yaml` file) from Bitnami (e.g. https://charts.bitnami.com/, or https://bitnami.com/stack/zookeeper/helm).  But no luck.
Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get default `values.yaml` from the GitHub repository or through the helm command.

```
helm show values bitnami/zookeeper > vaules.yaml
```

Or
From the GitHub repository, they have a link to the GitHub repository for every chart.

[bitnami/zookeeper/values.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/zookeeper/values.yaml)